# How do I monitor user activity on jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins

Using some plugin to record user activity on jenkins application by some authenticated user for tracking purpose.
Or by any other way??

Some plugin name or any other wayout.

To record user activity on the Jenkins application for tracking purposes, there are several approaches, including using plugins and other methods.

One popular plugin for Jenkins activity tracking is the "Audit Trail" plugin. This plugin allows you to monitor and record user actions within Jenkins. It logs information such as who performed an action, what action was taken, when it occurred, and more. By configuring the plugin, you can store these logs in a centralized location, such as a database or a file, for future analysis and auditing. This helps in tracking user activities, identifying potential issues, and ensuring compliance with security and governance requirements.

Alternatively, you can also consider using external monitoring and logging tools like Splunk, ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana), or Prometheus. These tools can integrate with Jenkins and provide detailed user activity tracking and visualization options.

Another method is to enable Jenkins' built-in access and command line history logs, which capture user interactions with the system. You can analyze these logs to track user activities.

Ultimately, the choice of method or plugin depends on your specific requirements, such as the level of detail needed, compliance standards, and the ease of integration with your existing monitoring and auditing infrastructure.